# Ubuntu command line? How to access it?

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Linux.  I now have i386 Desktop Ubuntu 14.04.4 on a PC with Intel CPU.  How do I access the command line to create a -p application folder in the usr\share folder?

Comment: Simply press ctrl+alt+t to open your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can either switch to a TTY by pressing `ctrl+alt+F1`, and login there, or start a terminal emulator, often by pressing `ctrl+alt+t`.